# How to chain methods according to checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

Can I store methods in a variable? Then how to use a variable as a method?
Or should I better create a function with a selector as a parameter?
I don't want to use eval.

Edit: My question is:
Is it possible to dynamically construct a chain with methods and apply it to an indicated DOM element?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check0">change color
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check1">change width
<div class="performedOn"></div>
<script>
var storedmethod = '';
if ($("#check0").prop("checked")==true) {
    var storedmethod = '.css({"background-color": "red"});';
    $(".performedOn")[storedmethod];
}
if ($("#check1").prop("checked")==true) {
    var storedmethod = storedmethod  + '.width(200)';
    $(".performedOn")[storedmethod];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the methods?

Comment: If you're doing this to change css (as per example) then you'd be better off using classes, storing those classes and using addClass/removeClass.

Comment: You can easily store methods as a variable (eg `function foo() { }; var bar = foo; bar();` - but you're not storing a method in your example code, you're storing a method call (with arguments), which is substantially different.  You could store an anonymous function and call it as required.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to acieive?

Comment: What I'm trying to achive exactly is to have a list of checkboxes 
for example:
[  ] change color
[x] widen
[x] move right
[  ] hide

and a submit button that checks which ones are checked and then I want to apply selected methods on a <div class="performedOn"> 
In this case:
$(".performedOn").width(200).left(200)

Comment: Basically my question is:
Is it possible to dynamically construct a chain with methods and apply it to an indicated DOM element?

 @freedomn-m - I agree that using addClass would be the best solution for this. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#check0').change(function(){
$('.performedOn').toggleClass('color')
})
$('#check1').change(function(){
$('.performedOn').toggleClass('width')
})
})
```

```css
.performedOn{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid #000; 
}
.color{
background-color:red
}
.width{
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check0">change color
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check1">change width
<div class="performedOn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I store methods in a variable? Then how to use a variable as a
>   method? Or should I better create a function with a selector as a
>   parameter? I don't want to use eval

Judging from what you are trying to achieve, you don't have to all of the above. Just bind the `change` event to the `checkbox`es

```
$("#check0").change(function(){
   if( $(this).prop("checked") == true ) {
       $(".performedOn").css({"background-color": "red"});
   }
})
$("#check1").change(function(){
   if( $(this).prop("checked") == true ) {
       $(".performedOn").css({"width": "200"});
   }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#check0").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $(".performedOn").css({
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  }
})
$("#check1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $(".performedOn").css({
      "width": "200"
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.performedOn
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check0">change color
<input type="checkbox" name="methods" id="check1">change width
<div class="performedOn"></div>
```